# How can I connect mongodb atlas to robomongo?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, robo3t, mongodb-atlas

I have my mongodb **4.0** running on mongodb atlas and I need to connect it Robo3t.

Where I can find the connection string on mongo atlas and how can I connect it robomongo?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes it is saying `Cannot connect to the MongoDB at cluster0-z9kan.mongodb.net:27017.`

Comment: And in the compass it is saying `MongoDB not running on the provided host and port

`

Comment: Have you [configured a whitelist entry](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/) to allow connections from your current IP to MongoDB Atlas? I would try to get a working connection with MongoDB Compass or the `mongo` shell before using third party tools. For MongoDB 4.0 server support you will also need Robo3T 1.3 or newer.

Comment: @Stennie You comment helps. I have downloaded the latest latest version of robo3t which has the option **From SRV** I have dirctly put my connection string over there and it is being connected. Thank you. Could you post it as answer it will help others.